# How to show that this Cayley Table does not form a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given the following Cayley Table (where e is the identity element):

[image: Cayley Table in question]

How would I go about proving that the table does not form a group?

I have checked closure, identity, inverses, and all 27 combinations of associativity excluding the ones that include the identity element.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't form a group?

Comment: It's surprisingly difficult to prove things that are false!

Comment: The Klein-4 group is not *in* Z4. There are two groups of order 4 (up to isomorphism), one is Z4, one is the Klein-4 group.

Comment: "The only group in Z4 is the Klein 4-group." This statement makes no sense, and I don't know what you mean. For example, you might mean "the only group (up to isomorphism) with 4 elements is the Klein 4-group." That statement is definitely false, but at least it is understandable. Or if this is not what you mean, perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: I was mistaken. So the above table does indeed form a group since I checked all the four conditions?

Comment: See also: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicGroupC4.html

Comment: If you've correctly checked the Group Axioms and your structure satisfies all of them, then it is a group!

Comment: With the translation $e=0$, $a=1$, $b=3$, $c=2$, our table is the addition table modulo $4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Can you write this sentence as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the translation $e=0$, $a=1$, $b=3$, and $c=2$, we can recognize that our table is the addition table modulo $4$. More formally, the structure $M$ with the given multiplication table is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_4$, via the mapping $\varphi$ that takes $e$ to $0$, $a$ to $1$, $b$ to $3$, and $c$ to $2$.  The fact that the table is a group table then follows from the standard fact that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is a group.